Why use a MOSFET and a BJT in this simple circuit?
As I was looking for a circuit, I noticed one that looks like this: 
It is used for the Vio pin, the level adapter of the TJA1051T/3 (Ref: https://www.mouser.vn/ProductDetail/NXP-Semiconductors/TJA1051T-3-1J?qs=Yna0arPQ0CSsef2%2FqMQJxA%3D%3D).
Can you explain why the circuit uses a BJT and a MOSFET to connect 3.3V and 3.3V_CAN together?

This circuit delays connecting CAN to 3v3 to about 5 seconds. The timing is more precise and predictable if use Vbe as reference (not Vgs).

R1 and C3 form a timer circuit that "turns on" Q2 which in turn pulls down the gate of Q1 and bridges 3.3V to 3.3V-CAN. Q2 is a BJT because it has a somewhat "sharper" turn-on characteristic than a MOSFET; Q1 is a MOSFET because the drain-source voltage drop across its Rds(on) is less than a typical BJT's Vce(sat).
Sharper turn-on characteristic means that as the control voltage rises, the turn-on happens faster (with smaller voltage rise). For a BJT, the control voltage is V(BE). For a MOSFET, the control voltage is V(GS).

BJTs are also cheaper, though it's less of a difference these days.

Can you explain to me what 'shaper turn-on' means? My technical skills are not very strong, and English is not my native language, so it is a little bit hard to understand. Thank you.

It is easier to turn ON the BJT, than a MOSFET. BJT have 0.6-0.7V Vbe, where a MOSFET can have several voltage of Vgs(th). And with a supply of 3.3V it is just easier with a BJT.

Also most MOSFETs cannot even turn on at 3.3V because their Vgs(th) is much higher.

Because the NPN is being used as a timer, the sharper turn on seems not to be a valid reason.
